# Get list of indices matching condition with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to get indices of elements that satisfies a condition in numpy array. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array([1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1])
np.where(ar==1)[0]
```

will return:

```
[0, 1, 3, 6]
```

Now if I want the condition to be a list of values like:

```
np.where(ar in [1, 2])[0]
```

I would like the result to be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 6]
```

How can I achieve this using numpy?
Of course I can iterate over my list of conditions and concatenate the results

```
indices = np.concatenate([np.where(ar==cond)[0] for cond in [1, 2])
```

But I would like to know if there's a more direct numpy-like way of doing this.

Comment: np.where(np.isin(ar, [1,2]))[0] works as well

Comment: The first answer of the marked duplicate does exactly what you are trying to do